# Excel webservice formula with Google-directions API

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, google-directions-api, directions

I would like to extract data in an Excel file from an XML result of a direction query.

I use the ServiceWeb function in Excel with this request:

```
=SERVICEWEB("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin="&A4&"&destination="&B4&"&mode=driving&key=MYKEY")
```

A4 is the origin: Place `Bastille, Paris` for example and in B4 is the destination address: Place `Bellecour, Lyon`.

I work in .xlsm file.

It seemed to work at first but not anymore. Am I missing something?

Comment: You mean the `WEBSERVICE` function: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/webservice-function-0546a35a-ecc6-4739-aed7-c0b7ce1562c4

Comment: @JMP Microsoft - being a total pain, as usual - have made the unbelievably stupid decision to TRANSLATE all function names to other languages. The `WEBSERVICE` function, in French, is called `SERVICEWEB`. Yeah!!! So, in case OP is working with a French version of Excel, the function is correct.

Comment: @MrUpsidown; i see; I tried it in my UK Excel, and it worked, so I thought OP had made a typo!